# "Etiquette to" vs. "Etiquette concerning."

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

Which sentence is correct?

"He doesn't know the etiquette to treat a woman."

"He doesn't know the etiquette concerning how to treat a woman."

Answer (score 3):

Etiquette does not take infinitival complements: <sup>∗</sup>*etiquette to treat* is not idiomatic

*Etiquette concerning* is acceptable, but fairly unlikely; we are more likely to speak about the *etiquette **of*** a particular situation or activity:  *the etiquette of the duello* or *the etiquette of a royal garden party* or *the etiquette of responding to an invitation*.

But *the etiquette of how to treat a woman* is repetitive: *how to* is pretty much built into the notion of *etiquette*.

And if you are speaking of behavior in the Anglo-American west, the very notion of an ***etiquette*** of treating a woman is iffy. In the first place, *etiquette* is concerned with prescribed behavior on formal occasions (even if in many cases the prescription is not formally expressed), and today there are not many formal occasions left to be governed by etiquette. In the second place, today we pretty much frown on marking women as a caste apart from men by any sort of formally marked behavior.

This of course does not prevent us from marginalizing, exploiting, degrading, and humiliating women ***informally*** in a rich variety of repulsive ways; but these behaviors do not fall under the strictures of *etiquette*.

---

<sup>∗</sup> *designates an unacceptable construction*

Comment: You give short shrift, with surprising venom, to a very important cultural phenomenon. _Etiquette_ is far from concerned only with formal occasions, but in any case cotillions, to name just one example, are no less common today than they ever were. Emily Post's institute is alive and well, etiquette and manners (like language) constantly evolve, and authors such as Ms Martin and Ms Toksvig would certainly take issue with some of what you imply here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have nothing against etiquette; I grew up in a highly formalized society and in many ways regret its passing. And I adore Miss Manners: no-one has done more than Judith Martin to teach us that as traditional etiquette fades its place must be filled by fundamental courtesy and civility.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Hi, I appreciate your concern. You raised a very interesting point. But this is a site for English learners. There are levels of learning a language. I think StoneyB's answer serves as a springboard on which a learner could dip further into a subject. It doesn't need to be all-inclusive. And there is the scope of subjectivity in the notion 'etiquette'. You might want to give an answer which addresses the specificity of the notion. That would help learners find out some more useful information by themselves.

Comment: @StoneyB It has not passed!

Comment: @P.E.Dant No; but the etiquette of the Victorian and Edwardian century moneyed classes, which is what most people mean when they speak of 'etiquette', is no longer something that most of either the moneyed or the not-so-moneyed aspire to emulate.

Comment: @StoneyB My children attended fortnightly just as I did, and at prep the boys still learn which fork is which. I think you're ringing down the curtain in middle of the second act.